# Why don't permissioned blockchains store their permissions in a blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

In all the examples of 'permissioned' blockchains that I've found; they store the permissions in a centralized database.

Why wouldn't they store them on each node, in a decentralized blockchain of transactions that contain the current state of the permissions on the network?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you tagged the question with hyperledger-fabric, I'll answer in that scope.

In Hyperledger Fabric - permissions are defined via membership of channels.
More precisely - a channel corresponds to a blockchain, and the members of a channel are defined as organizations that are in the channel.
Organizations in the channel are defined via MSP configurations, and the Fabric default MSP implementation uses x509 certificates to specify organizations, and members of organizations.

When a channel is created - these configurations (that define the permissions) are stored in the first block (genesis block) and later are updated via configuration blocks.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with @yacovm. Each member of the channel (of the Blockchain) stores all the blocks of the Ledger, also the genesis block. So, each node stores the specific configuration of each Blockchain.

Comment: This answer describes 'how' the permissions are managed; not, 'why' they aren't managed in a decentralised fashion. I believe, that is the intent of the original question.